# How to use TLS session tickets in iOS(Objective c) to mimimize Firebase Realtime Database download bandwidth and minimise the billing

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

I am using firebase realtime database in my iOS app.But the problem is the billing for high bandwidth.I also tried many solutions to reduce firebase download bandwidth. There are some blogs where they mentioned **"It seems that all of your connections are setup using websockets and the client running your application doesn’t support TLS session resumption."**

I also make AllowArbitaryloads in my plist.

```
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Please help me to set up this TLS session for my iOS application.